# statistics or robust statistics for identifying multivariate outliers

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, statistics, anomaly-detection, unsupervised-learning

For the single variate data sets, we can use some straightforward methods, such as box plot or [5%, 95%] quantile to identify outliers. For multivariate data sets, are there any statistics that can be used to identify outliers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multivariate outlier detection can be quite tricky and even 2D data can be difficult to visually decipher at times.  You are spot-on in looking for robust statistical treatments analogous to 95% quantiles.

Where as normally distributed data naturally aligns with the chi square distribution, the gold standard for robust statistics in n dimensions would be to use [`Mahalanobis distances`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) and then eliminate data beyond 95% or 99% quantiles in Mahalanobis space.

Plug and play capabilities are available in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/covariance/plot_mahalanobis_distances.html#example-covariance-plot-mahalanobis-distances-py) and in [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvoutlier/mvoutlier.pdf).

Here is an [excellent theoretical and practical treatment of the methodology](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a545834.pdf):

[image]

And here is a [big picture viewpoint with some heuristics](https://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2012/ams/slides/v2.2.pdf).

Additionally there is a very sophisticated treatments called `PCOUT` for outlier detection that instead rely on principal component decomposition.  There is a [corresponding R package](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/mvoutlier/docs/pcout), but the theoretical treatment is behind a paywall:

[P. Filzmoser, R. Maronna, M. Werner. Outlier identification in high dimensions, Computational Statistics and Data Analysis, 52, 1694-1711, 2008](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1315052)

Hope this helps!